# How could I load some data in FooTable after row was pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, footable

Here is example of some FooTable (jQuery plugin) from the internet: https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/azeYag

You could see that there is some data in html which is being shown after user press the row. For example, for the first row there is:

```
Spanish (official), English, Italian, German, French
```

Let's imagine that I have plenty of rows. There is good described solution how to load them with ajax help: https://fooplugins.github.io/FooTable/docs/examples/advanced/loading-rows.html

**However, I can't find a solution how to load data which is shown when I press on a row?** So, I don't want this data load before user press on specific row.

Comment: In the codepen example the Languages column is sometimes hidden if the screen size is small enough. Notice the "data-hide" attribute on that column in the HTML. If you view the page on a phone or a tablet the column will be hidden until you click on the row, and then it is displayed underneath the main row, to save horizontal space. The data itself was always there, it was just hidden. It does not get loaded via Ajax when the row is clicked, it simply gets shown/hidden on each click

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your comment, appreciate your support. So, that's mean that I have to write separate script to load additional data, right?

Comment: If you actually want to load it from the server separately, rather than just leave it hidden until clicked, then yes. (Note that if you wish, you can make it so a column is _always_ hidden initially, even on a big screen).

Comment: @ADyson Yes, true. I have made it (hide on all the screen). However, the problem is in a fact that there are many data in hidden rows, so when 100 rows are loaded than html page size is about 20k lines. As there are hidden rows bring such trouble I wanted to load them in individual way for every row separately and only when it is was pressed.

Comment: Why is it causing trouble exactly? Are you having performance issues? And 100 rows generating 20k lines...how many columns are you hiding???

Comment: @ADyson I have 8 basis columns and 10 hidden ones. But these hidden rows make complex solution with the business logic. For example one column includes user comments for the chosen row.  I don't have some performance issue, however, looks like there is not a right way to load so many data which is not going to be used maybe. Moreover there is visible issue on loading stage - part of these hidden rows are visible for few milliseconds when page is load.

Comment: Ok so that last point is a performance issue really - it's taking footable too long to apply the hiding rules. In that case yes I suspect you would be better to load each extra data separately when the row is clicked. You could either add it as another table row under the clicked one, or maybe display in a modal pop-up. I don't know, depends how you want your UI to work. Either way you have to add a click event handler to all rows and then make an Ajax request within that to get the extra information

Comment: @ADyson Right, agree, looks like adding additional separate pop-up or external row is more optimal way. Really appreciate your support and valuable comments you have provided. Wish you also good luck in all of your projects and efforts!